# Django 2.0 Queryset annotate date

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset, django-annotate

Is there a way to pass an F() expression to a function such as dateutil's **relativedelta** inside a database **annotate** call.

Given the below scenario where it is intended that **InterestLoan.objects.active_loans(start_date='2018-01-01', end_date='2019-01-01')** will return a queryset a of active loans within the given period. The **end_date** needs to be **annotated** using the **start_date** + **term**.

Instead I get TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'F'

```
class InterestLoanSet(models.QuerySet):
    def add_end_date(self):
        return self.annotate(loan_end_date=ExpressionWrapper(F('start_date') + relativedelta(months=+F('term'), output_field=DateField())))

    def active_loans(self, start_date, end_date):
        return self.exclude(start_date__gt=end_date).add_end_date().exclude(loan_end_date__lt=start_date)


class InterestLoan(AbstractTransaction):
    objects = InterestLoanSet.as_manager()
    interest_nominal_code = models.ForeignKey(NominalCode, null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    balance_nominal_code = models.ForeignKey(NominalCode, null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='loans')
    principal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    term = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    interest_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=4)
```

Comment: It compalins about the `+` in `relativedelta(month=+F('term'), ...)`.

Comment: Removing the '+' produces a different error:TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'F' @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: This isn't possible because the whole point of an expression is that it is done in the database. You will need to find an equivalent that can be converted to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution found following Daniel Roseman's comments that the expression needs to be taken care of in the database.

```
class InterestLoanSet(models.QuerySet):
    def add_end_date(self):
        return self.annotate(loan_end_year=ExpressionWrapper(ExtractYear('start_date') + F('term'), output_field=IntegerField()))

    def active_loans(self, range_start_date, range_end_date):
        return self.exclude(start_date__gt=range_end_date).add_end_date().exclude(loan_end_year__lt=range_start_date.year, start_date__month__lt=start_date.month)

class InterestLoan(AbstractTransaction):
    objects = InterestLoanSet.as_manager()
    interest_nominal_code = models.ForeignKey(NominalCode, null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    balance_nominal_code = models.ForeignKey(NominalCode, null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='loans')
    principal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    term = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    interest_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=4)
```

This filters at an annual level but will need to be made more sophisticated to filter at a month or day level.

Kudos to Kyle Hansan's [article](https://medium.com/@hansonkd/the-dramatic-benefits-of-django-subqueries-and-annotations-4195e0dafb16)